# Decodebin: skip a stream

Tags: gstreamer

I want to encode my TV recordings with Gstreamer on a raspberry pi. Inspired by [this post](https://blankstechblog.wordpress.com/2015/01/25/hardware-video-encoding-progess-with-the-raspberry-pi/), the following code works for a downloaded mkv:

```
/usr/bin/gst-launch-1.0 -e filesrc location=/media/Seagate/complete/TV/Better\ Call\ Saul/Season\ 01/Better\ Call\ Saul\ -\ S01E10\ -\ Marco.mkv ! decodebin name=demux ! queue ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw ! audiorate ! avenc_ac3 bitrate=320000 ! mux. mpegtsmux name=mux ! filesink location=/media/Seagate/pvr/Buitenhof_compressed.mkv demux. ! queue ! videoconvert ! deinterlace ! omxh264enc target-bitrate=2000000 control-rate=1 inline-header=true periodicty-idr=250 interval-intraframes=250 ! "video/x-h264,profile=high" ! h264parse ! mux.
```

The used file has this structure (gst-discoverer output):

```
Topology:
  container: Matroska
    audio: AC-3 (ATSC A/52)
    video: H.264

Properties:
  Duration: 0:49:18.048000000
  Seekable: yes
  Tags: 
      container format: Matroska
      audio codec: AC-3 audio
      language code: und
      video codec: H264
      minimum bitrate: 7288
      bitrate: 24263
      maximum bitrate: 9206
```

My recording software (TVHeadend) outputs this format however:

```
Topology:
container: Matroska
    subtitles: application/x-subtitle-unknown
    subtitles: application/x-subtitle-unknown
    audio: MPEG-1 Layer 2 (MP2)
    audio: AC-3 (ATSC A/52)
    audio: MPEG-1 Layer 2 (MP2)
    video: H.264

Properties:
  Duration: 0:00:06.440000000
  Seekable: yes
  Tags: 
      title: Buitenhof
      extended comment: DATE_BROADCASTED=2015-05-24 10:05:00
      container format: Matroska
      audio codec: MPEG 1 Audio, Layer 2
      language code: nl
      nominal bitrate: 256000
      has crc: true
      channel mode: stereo
      video codec: H264
      minimum bitrate: 8972400
      bitrate: 16546750
      maximum bitrate: 22841600
```

How can I tell the pipeline to skip the subtitlestreams and use the AC-3 and H264 streams? Ive tried `decodebin name=demux demux.audio_01` to no avail. The output is

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Missing element: application/x-subtitle-unknown decoder
Missing element: application/x-subtitle-unknown decoder
```

It would be nice to have the subtitles included as well, but I can certainly live without them.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the streams had nothing to do with with the problem. There was insufficient video memory available. For a full hd mkv I needed to set the video memory split to 128MB.

One way of doing this is running `sudo raspi-config` For my raspbian version de video memory split was under the advanced menu. Reboot required.

After this, the command I posted works

Comment: Additional hint if your input contains mpeg video: The omx hardware decoder on rpi requires you to buy a mpeg2 decoding license: http://www.raspberrypi.com/mpeg-2-license-key/